# How would I get a list of the top 5 frequent occurences, across multiple columns?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have 5 columns that look like this:

```
A              B              C              D
Selection A    Selection C    Selection G    Selection C
Selection B    Selection D    Selection C    Selection G
Selection C    Selection G    Selection J    Selection D
Selection D    Selection H    Selection A    Selection B
```

I want to get the top 5 choices (could also just list in order) from these columns, possibly with the count next to it (don't really need this, but just a nice to have). For the top example, it would look like this:

```
Selection C - 4
Selection D - 3
Selection G - 3
Selection A - 2
Selection B - 2
```

Only listing top 5 and listing the count aren't needed if it's hard to do. The other important thing to note is that the amount of data in the columns can change, and i'd like the list of top occurrences to update automatically. All I really need is a sorted list based on occurrences, just top 5 and the count are nice to have. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

List the seven candidates in **F1** thru **F7**

In **G1** enter:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$D$4,F1)
```

and copy down thru **G7**

Finally sort cols **F** & **G** by **G** descending.

Comment: Just updated OP. Is this possible if the data in the columns can change? I'd like the list to update automatically.

Comment: If you add/remove rows or increase the number of candidates, a macro could handle the re-calculation